# How to trigger callback using useState synchronously if callback was external

Tags: reactjs

I have the following hook:

```
const MessageStorage = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  const addMessage = (message) => { ... }
  
  const reset = (callback) => {
    setMessages([]) 
    callback(); // wrong since setMessages([]) is asynchronous
  }

  return { addMessage, reset };
}
```

The problem is with `reset` function. The standard approach to triggering callback is to use `useEffect` to track the change of state. But the problem is that callback is defined by the consumer of `MessageStorage` hook, and it must be defined as a parameter of `reset` function.
What's the best way to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to put the callback into state:

```
const [callback, setCallback] = useState();
// ...

  const reset = (callback) => {
    setMessages([]) 
    setCallback(callback);
  }
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  callback?.();
  setCallback(); // make sure callback only gets called once
}, [messages]);
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is 100% correct. What if I reached callback?.() before I set the callback `setCallback(callback)`?

Comment: Then nothing would run. It'll only run if the callback is defined.

Comment: Not sure if we are on the same page. To me, the dependency array should be `[messages, callback]`

```
useEffect(() => {
 if (callback) { callback(); setCallback() }
}, [messages, callback])
```

Comment: Sure, you could do that too. I guess that'll satisfy the exhaustive-deps linting rule, if that's what's presenting a problem.

Comment: I meant, if I am not mistaken, after you do `setMessages([])`, you go to the line `callback?.()` inside `useEffect`. How do you know `setCallback(callback)` finished before you go to that line?

Comment: No, React will wait for the current event loop to complete before re-rendering. All synchronous JS will complete, then the component will re-render. Then, a bit after the component re-renders (not synchronously!) the effect callback will run. So there are 2 asynchronous times in between when you call the state setter and the effect callback runs. React batches state updates: `setFoo(...); setBar(...)` will mean that both `foo` and `bar` will both be guaranteed to be updated to their new values on the next render.